# jQuery Fancybox on page load, content in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I would like to load a fancybox when the document is ready, but in a specific DIV and the content of the fancybox will be from a different page, displayed as an iFrame.  This is what I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
     $.fancybox({
          'href'            : "#div",
          'content'         : "content.jsp",
          'type'            : "iframe",
     });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Nothing is loading in.

Comment: You cannot display the contents of a `div` as iframe but inline, so choose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
     $("#div").fancybox({
          'href'            : 'content.jsp',
          'type'            : 'iframe'
     });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="div">
    Click Here
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17cdmvy6/1/)

Comment: it loads the content.jsp page, but now I have to CLICK on the div to get the fancybox to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display the contents of a `div` as *iframe* but *inline*.

So you either open (programmatically) the `content.jsp` file directly in fancybox as `iframe` like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fancybox({
        href: "content.jsp",
        type: "iframe"
    });
}); // ready
```

Or load the contents of the `content.jsp` file into the `div#div` container and then show that *inline* content in fancybox like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#div").load("content.jsp", function () {        
            $.fancybox($(this), {
                // API options
                type: "inline"
            });
    });
}); // ready
```